# Dropdown Button in UWP

Tags: uwp, dropdown, uwp-xaml

I'm unable to use the `DropDownButton` in my UWP app. Is there an extension or reference that I need to use before the control name?

If not, is there an alternative of the control?
I can't use the `ComboBox` as I need the header text in the button, not above it.

Comment: By unable to use, what exactly do you mean? It's just not appearing? Have you addded Microsoft,UI,XAML to your toolbox?

Comment: @McNline  I get the message "Dropdown button is not supported in UWP"

Comment: Set minimum version to 1809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the target version to 1809 or higher or install the [Windows UI Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml).

Don't fortget to add `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>` to your `Application.Resources` as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started).

Or add `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"` at the top of your XAML file and then add the control using `<controls:DropDownButton  />`.

Comment: @BellaSwan: Did you add `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>` to your `Application.Resources` as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started)? Or ` xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"` at the top of your XAML file and then `<controls:DropDownButton  />`?

Comment: May I know how to set the target version?

Comment: @BellaSwan: You get to select it when you create a new app. You can change it under Project->Properties->Application or by editing the `.appxmanifest` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the proper minimum version. It should work without any additional settings if you set the min target to Windows 10, version 1809.

Comment: WinUI provides backward compatibility.

Comment: @mm8 it still requires some min version, though different one.

Comment: Yes, the supported versions are listed in the docs. Upgrading to 1809 isn't required.

Comment: Also, it's the *target* version that determines which APIs that are available when building.

Answer (score 0):

Set Minimum Target version to 1809

Right click on Toolbox -> Choose Items -> Microsoft.UI.XAML

You should just be able to drag and drop like normal.